# Addition of an attribute to a Play request makes a new instance of request?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

If, like me, you're coming from the Java Servlet world, Play's support for request attributes (recently introduced in release 2.6) was only too long in coming. Now, that I've had a chance to look at it in some detail though, I wonder if it's usable.

Verbatim from the docs (Scala):

```
// Create a TypedKey to store a User object
object Attrs {
  val User: TypedKey[User] = TypedKey.apply[User]("user")
}
// Get the User object from the request
val user: User = req.attrs(Attrs.User)
// Put a User object into the request
val newReq = req.addAttr(Attrs.User, newUser)
```

I get and appreciate functional idea of immutable objects, but if this snippet is to be interpreted as that the act of adding an attribute to a request leaves me holding a new request, then what am I to do with it!? In the reactive world of callbacks, isn't the idea that *Play* passes the requests to *my* code, not the other way around? If I can't attach an attribute in an action and then inspect it in the error handler, what good is this?  Hopefully, I am just missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

You attach attributes to a request through a filter. 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters

The filter can then pass along the **new** request to the framework, which will then give it to your handler.

EDIT:

Passing the modified (new) request back to the framework:

```
...
nextFilter(requestHeader.addAttr(Attrs.User, newUser))
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alvaro. I am afraid, your answer seems off to me. For once, there are no examples of handing a request object back to the framework in the docs you're referencing. But even still, your answer is moot because I need to attach attributes in the action. Perhaps, this isn't the use case that the Play developers meant to cover, even though it's a very common technique in servlet programming.

Comment: The functional approach certainly is very different (read: better) from the java servlet world. If you provide a more concrete example of the what you're trying to achieve I may be able to help.

Comment: Well, as someone who's written a Lisp parser, I dig the advantages. But I am also not convinced that functional approach is better in all cases.

As to the use case: simple. I'd like to have an inheritance hierarchy of actions, which finally is possible in 2.6, since actions are classes now. There's plenty of state I need to maintain in an action, no matter now wrong it might seem to the purists. The safest way to do so is by attaching it to request, instead of managing it in an action itself.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. It is certainly possible it cannot be achieved in the way you expect. Can't say for sure without a more concrete problem. This in particular: "inheritance hierarchy of actions" sounds more like an expected solution to a problem than the problem itself.

Comment: I was simply responding to the "read: better" statement. I am happy to describe the actual issue at hand in more detail, but it will take more characters than a comment will allow. Please suggest the right format.

Comment: Either a new question, or modify this one describing the motivating problem leading to needing to maintain "plenty of state" in the actions. By the way, I'm not saying functional is always the best. But I've become increasingly reluctant to give it up easily, given the benefits yielded so far.

Comment: Opened this folllow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49742712/addition-of-an-attribute-to-a-play-request-makes-a-new-instance-of-request Many thanks in advance for your help, @Alvaro